# $f_*$ isomorphism $\Rightarrow$ $f$ isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider a Lie group endomorphism (bijective homomorphism) $f: G \rightarrow G$ and its pushforward $f_*: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$. I have seen that if $f$ is an isomorphism (a diffeomorphism) then $f_*$ is an isomorphism.

Is the converse true? That is, given a group endomorphism $f: G \rightarrow G$ with pushforward $f_*: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ an algebra endomorphism, is it true that if $f_*$ is an isomorphism, the $f$ is an isomorphism too?

Comment: It is obviously wrong if $G$ is not connected. Also, "endomorphism" doesn't mean that the map is bijective, it merely means that the domain and the target of the map are the same "space" or object.

Answer (score 1):

As Sebastian Schulz noted, the answer is obviously no if $G$ is not connected.

Furthermore, there are other Lie groups that have isomorphic Lie algebras, but which are not isomorphic since their global properties are different. A well-known example is given by $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$. The Lie algebras of these groups are isomorphic, but the groups themselves are not: in fact, $SU(2)$ is the double cover of $SO(3)$.

Comment: He did specifically start with an endomorphism of Lie groups though (so a covering map between Lie groups with isomorphic Lie algebras is not ruled out)

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the minimal example that I could think of for a connected Lie group. Take $G = U(1) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | |z| = 1 \}$, it allows endomorphisms of the form $\phi_n : z \mapsto z^n$.

The Lie algebra of $U(1)$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and the derivative of $\phi_n$ is just multiplication by $n$ (which is an isomorphism unless $n=0$). However, unless $n= \pm 1$, the map is not injective on the level of Lie groups, so it is not an isomorphism.